# Select element in order by user clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I view the values of the selected options in order properly?
I used the the changed.bs.select function to do this. Please help me.
For example:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

My selection sequence is ***2, 3, 1***.
I want to get the val() of `["2", "3", "1"]` but it gives me `["1", "2", "3"]`.

```
$('#myselect').on('changed.bs.select', function () {  
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

I saw in this [link] (https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/603) that this is possible.
This issue was archived but I don't know how to do it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will have to use the `changed.bs.select` event to store the selected value in another variable each time the select list is clicked, the select list itself won't know in what order you actually click the items.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. Yes I've done that. I added this code to capture all the selected items.
    `optionValues = $('option:selected', this).map(function() {`
      `return this.value;`        
    `}).get();`

  `alert(optionValues);`

But it's not in the order that i wanted.